# What is the difference between Interval and ThrottleInterval in launchd.plist

Tags: launchd

I found `Interval` key in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic-daily.plist` from my MacOS  10.13.6. But I fail to find what `Interval` is by googling. Even `man launchd.plist` does not have this key. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between StartInterval and ThrottleInterval is that StartInterval means that the program should be started after x seconds (more or less precisely), whereas ThrottleInterval means that the program should NOT be started again less than x seconds after it was last started.

So StartInterval is used to schedule something to run every X seconds, where ThrottleInterval is used when you schedule something to run based on other criteria, but don't want it to run too often.

"Interval" does not seem to be a valid key - it is not in the man page, as you describe, but nor is it in the source code released by Apple. Either it is a mistype for "StartInterval", or it seems Apple has included "Interval" as an alias for "StartInterval" in their own builds.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Did you look at your `com.apple.periodic-daily.plist` file? Does it have `Interval` key too? I really want to find an official doc about this key, because it's in the built-in MacOS daemon which really confuses me.

Comment: Yes, and yes it does. There's no official doc that mentions it. Nor does the source code.